# Select a string to find, and then select a part of a string 3 lines up from the found word

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to do the following:
I am trying to search for a word and then once the word is found I need to go 3 lines up and read characters 34 to 42 and print those out.

Test file:

1. I am going for a long walk here we walk walk walk down to the river
   yadda yadda.
2. lalalalala - she says
3. roll roll roll he says
4. the well was dry

What I have: 
select-string $TestFile -pattern "well" -simplematch 3{34,42}

What I can't figure out:
How to print out the "walk walk walk" part.

What happens is every time it prints out the whole lines 1. 2. and 3. 
I just need the one part "walk walk walk"

I am using this for log files if that helps. In the file the word error is 3 lines below the error code, usually a string, above it.

Comment: why not use the -context parameter of select-string?

Comment: I can get -context 3, to print the 3rd line up but how do i select a word within that string? 3{35,15} doesn't change the value output.

Comment: `PS>(gc C:\temp\sls.txt |sls "test" -Context 3).context |select -ExpandProperty precontext |select -first 1`

Comment: sls is the alias for select-string (only available in powershell V3)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Context parameter:

```
PS> (Get-ChildItem $TestFile | Select-String well -Context 3).Context.PreContext[-3].Substring(35,15)
walk walk walk
```

Comment: Shay, Anyway you can phrase that as a script instead of using Pipes.

Comment: I set the string to a text file and then set it to a variable. Tried doing $blah2 = ($text select-string -path textfile.txt -pattern "well" - context).Context.PreContext[-3].Substring(35,15)
This ended in an error when I tried to print out $blah2

Comment: Sorry, something went wrong when I pasted the command, add '3' after the context parameter. See the updated command.

Comment: Still get an error after PreContext[<<<<-3] .. Error says NullArray or Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: What's the count in here and does the line in question is not blank? (Get-ChildItem $TestFile | Select-String well -Context 3).Context.PreContext.Count

Comment: The count can change, varies on the log. Line in question is not blank.

Comment: So, when you print PreContext, which lines holds the information?

Comment: I think this is a v3 only syntax ().context

Comment: I believe we are running 1.0.

Comment: I'm guessing I have to make this a Foreach statement since there are multiple in the document. And I am trying to print them out.

Comment: The Context parameter was introduced in v2.